# Image height exceeds container with appended element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am checking to see if the div `smallCatalogBlock` if `data-availability="No"` and if it is no, then `soonOverlay` is appended to the `smallCatalogBlockImg` div.

The issue I am having is getting the `soonOverlay` height to only cover the image. Right mow, it exceeds the image container and fills the entire `smallCatalogBlock` div.

What could I do to only cover `smallCatalogBlockImg`?

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('availability') === 'No') {
   $(this).find('.smallCatalogBlockImg').append('<div class="soonOverlay"><div class="soonOverlayInner"><div class="total-center"><p class="dGw">Coming Soon</p></div></div></div>');
  }
 });
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 60px 0;
}
.smallCatalogBlock {
 width: 45%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.smallCatalogBlock img {
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}
.smallCatalogTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.comingSoonSmall {
 position: relative;
}
.comingSoonSmall .soonOverlay {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 opacity: .8;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
.soonOverlayInner {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 350px;
}
.soonOverlayInner .dGw {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
    <div class="smallCatalogBlockImg">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="A">
    </div>
  <span class="smallCatalogTitle">A</span>
</div><div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
    <div class="smallCatalogBlockImg">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="B">
    </div>
  <span class="smallCatalogTitle">B</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to position the overlay's parent relatively. Only then can the overlay be (absolutely) positioned and sized in relation to its parent.

[Read more here.](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('availability') === 'No') {
    $(this).find('.smallCatalogBlockImg').append('<div class="soonOverlay"><div class="soonOverlayInner"><div class="total-center"><p class="dGw">Coming Soon</p></div></div></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.smallCatalogBlock {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.smallCatalogBlock img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}

.smallCatalogTitle {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.comingSoonSmall {
  position: relative;
}

.comingSoonSmall .soonOverlay {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #b82222;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.soonOverlayInner {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 350px;
}

.soonOverlayInner .dGw {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.smallCatalogBlockImg {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlockImg">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="A">
  </div>
  <span class="smallCatalogTitle">A</span>
</div>
<div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlockImg">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="B">
  </div>
  <span class="smallCatalogTitle">B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, such a dumb overlook on my part. Thanks for the help!